# How to check current user's permissions from a Group in Django?

Tags: django, permissions, django-users, django-permissions

I have a group `EuropartsBuyer` and model named `Product`.

The following code adds a permission to the Product model.

```
class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_add_cost_price", "Can add cost price"),
        )
```

In one of my views I have the following code to add this permission to that group.

```
europarts_buyer, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='EuropartsBuyer')
add_cost_price = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_add_cost_price')
europarts_buyer.permissions.add(add_cost_price)
```

With the help of Django Admin I have added a user to the group `EuropartsBuyer`.

When I use the following code in another view

```
if request.user.has_perm('can_add_cost_price'):
    do something
```

the result is supposed to be `True` but it is showing `False`. Thus, the code under the if clause doesn't run.

I have imported the currently logged in user in Django shell and when I test the permission again it shows False.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check if the request.user is a AnonymousUser instance?

Comment: @ThulasiRam Yes. I have to log in to access that particular view.

Comment: That i get but If you use DRF and removed authentication classes although you are logged in..in the request the user will be Anonymous. So can you try printing request.user first before checking for permissions that way you can be sure. @MiniGunnR

Comment: I did. The user is logged in.

Comment: I forgot to use the app label. Now it's working. `if request.user.has_perm('europarts.can_add_cost_price')`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this:

```
if request.user.has_perm('app_name.can_add_cost_price'):
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin.has_perm):

> where each perm is in the format 'app_label.permission codename'

Comment: The convention is now <app>.<action>_<modelname>. See https://realpython.com/manage-users-in-django-admin/

Answer (score -1):

When you are working with permissions groups you don't need to check for each permission the user has. If the user is part of the permission group you created in the Django admin just change "YourGroupName" to the name your called your group when you created it

```
        {% ifequal user.groups.all.0.name "YourGroupName" %}
          <div>This is User</div>
        {% endifequal %}
```

Comment: The zero limits you to check only one group.
Also, the calculations in the view have been performed and you are checking too late if the server should perform something. Permissions are a way to even limit the server's overhead.